# How to solve coupled ODEs?

Tags: analysis

$\frac{da}{dx}=b+c-0.1x$;
$\frac{du}{dx}=-u+c$;
$\frac{db}{dx}=-0.51(u-b)$;
$\frac{dc}{dx}=a-u$

How to solve these equations numerically and in matlab? Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Use `ode45`, you can find explanation in mathworks.

Comment: It's an inhomogeneous linear system, so it can be solved exactly: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx